# Generate a non-unique number for a set of results from one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I want to get. As you can see, a uniq column has the same non-unique value for all of the 10 results.

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | uniq       |
+--------+------------+
| 714183 | 1514152300 |
| 714184 | 1514152300 |
| 714185 | 1514152300 |
| 714186 | 1514152300 |
| 714187 | 1514152300 |
| 714188 | 1514152300 |
| 714189 | 1514152300 |
| 714190 | 1514152300 |
| 714191 | 1514152300 |
| 714192 | 1514152300 |
+--------+------------+
```

and this is the next select

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | uniq       |
+--------+------------+
| 714202 | 1514152302 |
| 714201 | 1514152302 |
| 714200 | 1514152302 |
| 714199 | 1514152302 |
| 714198 | 1514152302 |
| 714197 | 1514152302 |
| 714196 | 1514152302 |
| 714195 | 1514152302 |
| 714194 | 1514152302 |
| 714193 | 1514152302 |
+--------+------------+
```

```
  select id, floor(avg(unix_timestamp())) uniq 
    from sites2 
   where status=0 
group by id limit 10;
```

and this is the best i could come up with. The problem is, that I need to wait 1 second each time in order to get these results. What can be a better solution? Format doesn't matter, it can be an integer of any size.

Comment: toothache. why call it unique if it is not?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sry, I meant non-unique =)

Comment: 5 times `uniq` is used in your question (including 2x"unique") that's quite some confusion. What is the purpose of this non-unique value, is it some sort of natch number? if not that, what?

Comment: no, wait. it's a non-unique value which is unique for this exact set of results, so the next set will have another non-unique value.
the purpose of this number is to distinguish between different sets of result.
for example, 1st select will assign 1514152300 for all the 10 results, and the next select will assign 151321 for the next 10 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more precision, you can use `unix_timestamp(now(6))`:

```
select id, unix_timestamp(now(6))
from sites2 
where status = 0 ;
```

(I don't think the `group by` is necessary.)

This returns a number with a decimal point.  If that is an issue, you can multiple by 1,000,000 and convert to a decimal/bigint.

Comment: perfect, didn't know it's possible to get more precision. thank you.